# Change mat-select-arrow and mat-select-underline when focused

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

So far I've tried lots of different things, such as:

```css
/deep/ .mat-select:focus .mat-select-trigger .mat-select-arrow {
    color: #63961C;
}

/deep/ .mat-select:focus .mat-select-trigger .mat-select-underline {
    background-color: #63961C;
}
```

Or :

```css
/deep/ .mat-select.mat-focused .mat-select-trigger .mat-select-arrow {
    color: #63961C;
}

/deep/ .mat-select.mat-focused .mat-select-trigger .mat-select-underline {
    background-color: #63961C;
}
```

to change that little arrow next to a select, and the underline.

For example, I did

```css
/deep/ .mat-input-container.mat-focused .mat-input-underline {
    background-color: #63961C;
}
```

for the underline of an Input, and it worked fine (it becomes green when focusing). (yes /deep/ works fine for this project, though it's deprecated now if I remember well)

I managed to change it "all the time", but what I want, is to have it **green only on focus**, and keep it **grey if not focused**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Avoid using `/deep/` (read this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)). You should use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).

In your ts file, set ViewEncapsulation to None:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

.. and add the following classes to your component's css file:

```
/* to change arrow when focused */
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-arrow {
    color: #63961C;
}

/* to change underline when focused */
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-underline {
    background-color: #63961C;
}

/* to change plceholder text when focused */
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-trigger {
    color: #63961C;
}

/* to change selected item color in the select list */
.mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
    color: #63961C;
}
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckcw3g?file=app%2Fapp.component.css).

> To make the css shorter,

```
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary 
.mat-select-arrow , .mat-select-underline , .mat-select-trigger 
{
    color: #63961C;
}

/* to change selected item color in the select list */
.mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
    color: #63961C;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! If I understand it well, encapsulation is set to emulated by default in Angular ? Anyway I'll get rid of these /deep/ in the other part of the project.

Comment: Yes the default is emulated. Yes get rid of `/deep/`, `::ng-deep` in your project, that is not angular standard and maybe depreciated/removed in future.

Comment: I don't understand the benefit. If we set ViewEncapsulation.None then all the CSS styles will not be bound to that particular component. It will be applied to all the elements in the whole project with same class names. So there will be more chances of conflict. So how is this even beneficial? @Faisal

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your style.css

```
    .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow {
        color: blue;
    }    
    .mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
        color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because then you don't lose the benefits of ViewEncapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

For angular material 2 and setting the underline for inputs I have to set:

```
.mat-form-field-ripple {
background-color: red;
}
```