# Angular Material mat-select underline color change in Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular Material, so I may be missing something, but I would appreciate any help on this case. 
My goal is to change the default blue underline of mat-select tag to white color while it is on focus. I managed to deal with this by adding this code to global styles file of my project:

```
.mat-select-value, .mat-select-arrow{
    color: #fff !important;
}

.mat-form-field-infix{
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey !important;
}

.mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple{
     background: none; 
}
```

You can see how it looks [here](https://financial-inspector.netlify.com/) (language selection dropdown list in top left corner).

After that I realized, that i will need some more mat-select tags in another components, but the underline this time should not be white, but black. Thats why I need my problem to be solved by changing component styles, but still nothing works for me. So far I tried to use !important to reset Angular Material attributes, ng-deep and switching encapsulation mode to "None".

I also inspected this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280619/change-mat-select-arrow-and-mat-select-underline-when-focused?rq=1) with similar problem, but it seem a bit outdated and after my rework still didn't work for me.

This is the html template, that i'm using

```
<div id="languageDropDown">
    <mat-form-field id="languageSelector">
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="language" name="languageSelector" id="languageSelector" (selectionChange)="languageChanged()">
        <mat-option value="en" selected="selected" >EN</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="ua">UA</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

I am using: @angular/material@6.3.1, Angular: 6.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style.css

when focused

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
    background-color: red;
}
```

when Normal

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me

```
// this is the underline when hovered
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: red !important;
}
// this is the normal
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

it does not work without ::ng-deep or !important, i think because angular overwrites this style somewhere down the line when generating html and css elements

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for the answer, but someone hopefully find it helpful. After hours of surfing through the browser inspect, I finally managed to find the answer.

- normal underline (no appearance variant)

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: red;
}
```

- normal underline with appearance variant used (ex: appearance='fill') ([More on appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants))

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: red;
}
```

- underline when focused

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Be sure to use ::ng-deep for angular to be able to overwrite these styles.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of modifying the original mat-* classes why not add your own classes and invoke the proper one at the HTML level?

So:

```
    <mat-form-field class="blackunderline" id="languageSelector"> .. </mat-form-field>
```

Or:

```
    <mat-form-field class="whiteunderline" id="languageSelector"> .. </mat-form-field>
```

And in your component's CSS (or global CSS if you prefer):

```
.blackunderline {
     ...
 }

.whiteunderline {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I've already tried both common html classes and panelClass attribute, which is offered by Angular Material(the demo of which doesn't even work on their official website), but I had no success. Maybe I don't understand what should i write inside these classes? E.g. I need to redesign a div tag with a class mat-form-field-underline, which is rendered form mat-form-field tag. If you ment that I should set background color of mat-form-field to needed it doesn't work for me, even with "!important".